# Which boundary condition to delimit air volume body to the atmospheric environment (ANSYS)

Tags: simulation, ansys, ansys-workbench, fluent, boundary-layer

I simulate the air flow into a cooling tank due to the temperature or density differences with the environment.
I have represented the environment as an air volume body and would like to select the correct boundary condition at the boundaries to the further ambient air. Which boundary condition should I use?

According to the documentation, the outflow boundary condition does not seem to be the correct one and, when used, causes the outflowed cool air to "pile up" at these boundaries.

It would be highly appreciated if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

[image: Picture of my Simulation]